# Posting Facebook status including a link to a photo already on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a Facebook status update, using the Facebook iOS API, with a message and a link to a photo that is already on Facebook. I have already obtained the URL of the image using the result of an another graph API call. I have already set the App to have permissions for read_stream, publish_stream, offline_access and user_photos.

When I post the image as part of a status update, I receive the error "The operation couldn't be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)". However, if I attempt to post an image not already on Facebook, the status update posts fine and the image is shown.

This is strange as if I attempt to do the same in Facebook on the web by posting to my wall, I can include a link to the image that is in Facebook, which works fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong attempting to include an image already in Facebook? The call I'm using is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"CIAO",@"message",
                               @"http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/<rest_of_the_image_url>.jpg", @"picture",
                               nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can no longer post images hosted by Facebook. From the Facebook Developers page on [Stream Attachements](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/):

> Don't reference images that are hosted on the fbcdn.net domain. The images associated with these URLs aren't always optimized for stream stories and occasionally resulted in errors, leading to a poor user experience. Make sure your stream attachments don't reference images with this domain. You should host the images locally.

However, the error you should have received is:

```
{
  error: {
    type: "OAuthException",
    message: "(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream: http://graph.facebook.com/100001717292608/picture",
  }
}
```

Comment: So, it's impossible. The only way to do this seems using an external image provider (the same mechanism on with for example Instagram is based).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the "object_attachment" tag instead of "picture".  This will allow you to use a picture in your album as the icon of a timeline or wall posting.  Just take the id of the uploaded image as returned in `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result`

Read more here:  [Attaching Existing Facebook Photos to Wall Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/)

Comment: It seems like they allow it only for user album photos?
[Fb post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526)

What about a video src image? I can't seem to succeed :(

Comment: I haven't tried video.  I would start with making sure that the first post to your application album worked, and then do a second post using the objectID you get back from the first.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to use an image that exists on any album... Only an FB src image I'm getting a link to from a video object...